# Ran Rails 3 bundler with --deployment option on development, how to roll back

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3

I ran rails 3 bundler with the deployment option (Yes I know I was not supposed to and I am paying for it).  And it is stuck in deployment mode, it won't use system installed gems.  It is only using the vendor/bundle.  I thought I could roll back any changes.  But I can't figure out what changed.  I tried:

- Switching Ruby's with RVM
- Rolled back everything in my project directory.
- Deleted the ~/.bundler directory.
- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the bundler gem

I couldn't figure out a way to find any bundler config files that could have been changed by the --deployment option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the .bundle directory.  I didn't see it because I was relying on 'git status'  So removing this should do the trick.